# exclamation mark in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am building a forum and the urls contain the title of the topic you are going to view. but if it contains a ! then it throws a 404 error. i know the ASCII character for ! is %21 and i assumed urlencode() would change the ! to %21 but it doesnt. When i click the link the url still contains the ! which is breaking the url. Any tips?

Comment: urlencode should work, but you can also try rawurlencode()

Comment: Please post your code. I just tested php's [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function and it does indeed encode `!` to `%21`. Something else must be going on with your code.

Comment: im simply using this:
urlencode($forum['last_post_topic']);
in my <a> tag.
$forum['last_post_topic'] in the database looks like
Asf is awesome!

but when i click the link the url reads
ASF+is+absolutely+awesome!

so urlencode() is replacing the spaces but not the exclamation mark

Comment: ive managed to narrow it down using a test script. echoing urlencode('!TEST!/?TEST?'); works as normal. echoing a database value also works: echo urlencode($row['f_last_post']); but when i put the encoded database value in a link it doesnt work!
echo '<a href="'.urlencode($row['f_last_post']).'">'.$row['f_last_post'].'</a>'; shows - ASF+is+absolutely+awesome! as the link. so why doesnt urlencode work when its in an <a> tag?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with "native" functions to encode URL. Related to some characters, take a look on this: http://www.dwfaq.com/tutorials/miscellaneous/special_links_encoding.asp

Comment: Please edit the question and provide all the information there, properly formatted. Code in comments is unreadable and the question, as it's now, lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you normalize the title you want to use in the url, in order to make it safe to use and keep it readable for users.

```
$normalizedTitle = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', strtolower($title)), '-');
```

This will turn `!TEST!/?TEST?` into `test-test`, and `ASF is absolutely awesome!` into `asf-is-absolutely-awesome`.